# Send request line + File using Sockets - java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream

I am trying to send a "request line" and a file through a socket.

**Client** (sender)

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, SOCKET_PORT);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
os.writeBytes("PUT c:\dev\foo\helloworld.txt" + "\r\n")
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;
while((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
    try {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

**Sever** (receiver)

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT);
Socket clientSoc = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream inputStream = clientSoc.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String requestLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
File currentFile = (File)new ObjectInputStream(inputStream).readObject(); //This doesn't work
byteSequence = new byte[new Long(currentFile.length()).intValue()];
for(int i =0; i<currentFile.length();i++){
    byteSequence[i] = (byte)clientSoc.getInputStream().read();
} 
try {
    FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream(currentFile.getName());
    newFile.write(byteSequence,0, byteSequence.length);
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I am able to read the request line on the server but when I attempt to read the file it throws an exception (line below).

```
File currentFile = (File)new ObjectInputStream(inputStream).readObject();
```

java.io.Stream.CorruptedException:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A48656C
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `it throws an exception` Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access an object that was not even passed to the socket.. you only passed a byte of string to the server but you never pass an Object to the server using the ObjectOutputStream..

Comment: Should I be using 2 separate streams for text & files? @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @ojhawkins depends but before that are you even passing an object of file to the stream?

Comment: I Believe so. On the client in the while loop I am reading the `FileInputStream` and writing it into the output stream of the socket. @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @ojhawkins no you are not.. youre only writings bytes of data to the output stream not object to enable you to readObject() you must use the ObjectOutputStream but i coudnt see it there..

Comment: Ok let me try that @Rod_Algonquin